# Persistent BackTrack on USB

Tags: linux, installation, usb-flash-drive, backtrack

Can someone explain how to make a persistent installation of BackTrack 5 on an 8GB USB drive?

Comment: Did you check the FAQs at their site?  There is this link as well http://www.infosecramblings.com/backtrack/backtrack-4-usbpersistent-changesnessus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is with the 
[Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Wiki on backtrack-linux.org? It's full of very useful information, by the way.

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Persistent_USB

Answer (score 0):

Also try using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It's like Universal USB installer